# How are Elastic Net penalties applied to Logistic Regression's Maximum Likelihood cost function?

Tags: regression, logistic-regression

I understand how Ridge / Lasso / Elastic Net regression penalties are applied to the linear regression's cost function, but I am trying to figure out how they are applied to Logistic Regression's Maximum Likelihood cost function.

I've tried looking into pages through google, and it looks like it can be done (I believe Sci-Kit's logistic regression models accept L1 and L2 parameters, and I've seen some YouTube videos saying that the penalties can be applied in logistic models too) and I've found how they are added to the sum of squared residuals cost function, but I am curious on how the penalties are applied with the Maximum Likelihood cost function.  Is it Maximum Likelihood minus the penalties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer by posting on stats stack exchange ([link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/545695/math-behind-applying-elastic-net-penalties-to-logistic-regression)).  I'll post the answer from [ofer-a](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/165474/ofer-a) here to help you all searching on Stack Overflow for a similar answer.

> The elastic net terms are added to the maximum likelihood cost function.i.e. the > final cost function is:
> [image: Latex: \sum_{i = 0}^{N}\bigg[- (y\log(p) + (1-y)\log(1-p))\bigg] + \lambda_1 \sum_{i=0}^{k}|w_i| + \lambda_2 \sum_{i=0}^{k}w_i^2]

> The first term is the likelihood, the second term is the l1 norm part of the elastic net, and the third term is the l2 norm part. i.e. the network is trying to minimize the negative log likelihood and also trying to minimize the weights.